# Typescript declare module error

Tags: typescript, module

I have the following module declaration in myModule.d.ts file

```
declare module Auth0Wrapper{
  export function Login();
  export function Logout();
}
```

Now I am trying to use this in my .ts file using the following code

```
import {Login} from '../modules/myModule';
```

Now I get the following error
**myModule.d.ts is not a module**  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 declare module myModule{
```

Also in you `tsconfig.json`:

```
"types": [
    "<DIR_THAT_CONTAINS_MYMODLUE_D_TS>"
]
```

Comment: I added the following to my tsconfig.json file
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types",
      "./app/modules"
    ]

./app/modules is where my myModule.d.ts file is.  I have renamed the file to the following
declare module myModule{
  export function Login();
  export function Logout();
}

However I still get the following cannot find module myModule

Comment: And? Did it work? If not, what's the error now? Same?